# Using St_expand and St_Squaregrid work together in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, geometry-data-type

Using this query (which works), I am able to create a square grid.

```sql
select 
  ST_asGeoJSON(geom) 
from 
  (
    select 
      ST_SquareGrid(
        0.0001, 
        ST_Transform(
          ST_GeomFromText(
            'POLYGON((548840.003869398 4180149.81350724,548839.641707047 4180151.92257034,548888.51251476 4180159.99856712,548888.863420189 4180157.81158342,548840.003869398 4180149.81350724))', 
            32610
          ), 
          4326
        )
      ) as geom
  ) as T1;
```

Looks like this:
[image]

I just want to use these polygons and expand them individually.

So I tried this query:

```sql
select 
  ST_asGeoJSON(ST_Expand(geom,0.001)) 
from 
  (
    select 
      ST_SquareGrid(
        0.0001, 
        ST_Transform(
          ST_GeomFromText(
            'POLYGON((548840.003869398 4180149.81350724,548839.641707047 4180151.92257034,548888.51251476 4180159.99856712,548888.863420189 4180157.81158342,548840.003869398 4180149.81350724))', 
            32610
          ), 
          4326
        )
      ) as geom
  ) as T1;
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  function st_expand(record, numeric) does not exist
LINE 2:   ST_asGeoJSON(ST_Expand(geom,0.001)) 
                       ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

What am I doing wrong or how do I cast a Record type to Geometry type?

Comment: Just wanted to add that `ST_SquareGrid()` was added in Postgis 3.1. So anyone tries my queries above, they won't work if you have an older Postgis. You can find out your Postgis version information using this query `select postgis_full_version();`.

Comment: Do you really want them expanded *individually* (introducing overlaps between them), in contrast to having a larger overall grid cell size?

Comment: Yes, overlap of individual squares is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ST_SquareGrid` is a [*set-returning*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html#FUNCTIONS-SRF-SERIES) function (see also [*Table functions*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS)), returning a non-defined `SETOF RECORDS`, having a `geom` member, as well as `i` & `j` (*row* and *column*) indexes.

`RECORDS` themselves are [*composite* (or *`ROW`*) types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html) and need to be accessed through field decomposition.

---

In order to run subsequent operations on the individual geometries inside the set returned by `ST_SquareGrid`, and with constant parameters passed to the function (in contrast to dynamic injection via e.g. `JOIN`s), you'd want to simply make the function a `FROM` item:

```
SELECT
  ST_Expand(grid.geom, 0.0001) AS geom
FROM
  ST_SquareGrid(
    0.0001, 
    ST_Transform(
      ST_GeomFromText(
        'POLYGON((548840.003869398 4180149.81350724,548839.641707047 4180151.92257034,548888.51251476 4180159.99856712,548888.863420189 4180157.81158342,548840.003869398 4180149.81350724))', 
        32610
      ), 
      4326
    )
  ) AS grid
;
```

Comment: I tried this out, and wow, this is exactly what I needed. I was so close, thanks this solved my issue.